# on production db I happen to be logged as postgres but postgres does not own my tables so I can't see the content

Tags: postgresql

I am on my production terminal.
I went to do some operations on my db, but for some reason, while the tables are definitively not empty as I see the results on the web, I never get any result from this.

First I display my tables

```
postgres=# \l
                                List of databases
     Name      |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |   Access privileges   
---------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+-----------------------
 django_boards | u_boards | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 
 postgres      | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | 

postgres=# \c django_boards
You are now connected to database "django_boards" as user "postgres".

schema |             Name              | Type  |  Owner   
--------+-------------------------------+-------+----------
 public | account_emailaddress          | table | u_boards
 public | account_emailconfirmation     | table | u_boards
 public | auth_group                    | table | u_boards
 public | auth_group_permissions        | table | u_boards
```

etc etc

but actually postgres does not own that table, it is a user called u_boards So, how can I change to that user? I suppose this is th e problem

```
Then I want to display the rows of pics at it comes up empty but it is not.
django_boards=# \dt
django_boards=# SELECT * from scaffoldapp_photos
django_boards-# nothing comes out
```

I also have a table of countries and I can see all countries picked by the select lists on the web.

What am I missing? is it because I am connected as postgres and since postgres does not own that table I can't see anything? how can I switch to u_boards user?

Comment: 1) `postgres` is a superuser(in most cases) it can see everything so that is not the issue. 2) This `SELECT * from scaffoldapp_photos` will not complete as it needs a terminating `;` so `SELECT * from scaffoldapp_photos;`. 3) If you want to connect as a specific user then use  `-U <user_name> ` when connecting with `psql`. From here [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) read section *Connecting to a Database*. In fact it would be a good idea to at least scan the entire page.

Comment: thank you, indeed I had missed the ; I noticed that later. I have seen that can switch user by doing thisn SET role u_boards and this switches me to the user and now I can see the contents of the table

Comment: @Alvar That's really weird. Can you [edit] your question to include the outputs of `\du+`, please?

Comment: You can see the contents because you terminated the query correctly.

Comment: The only explanation for this is that either `postgres` is not a superuser and row level security is enabled on the tables, or that you are using a fork of PostgreSQL where the permission system was hacked up in a weird fashion.

Answer (score -1):

```
SET role u_boards;
```

that is all it took, it is the command I neeed to switch user. Special thanks to Adrian Klavier who clarified to me some lack of understanding I had regarding the postgres user